# What is the index of the pixel in RGBA theory

Tags: swift, rgba

Say you have an image that is 128 pixels wide, by 128 pixels high, and it is represented by a one-dimensional array of 32-Bit integers.

> (Each integer contains the RGBA information for one pixel).

If the pixels are arranged in row-major order

> (that is, the top row of pixels takes up array indices 0…127, the
>   second row down is in 128… 255, and so on)

then what is the index of the pixel at x=15, y=22 (y=0 at the top)?

Comment: The correct formula is y * (image width) + x.

Comment: my man came straight on SO just to complete Swift coursera course quiz 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The formula

```
index = y * width + x
```

#### Example

Say you have an image that is 128 pixels wide, by 128 pixels high, and it is represented by a one-dimensional array of 32-Bit integers.

```
2831 = 128 * 22 + 15
```